# How to select rows with similar values?

Tags: r, filter, rounding

I would like to remove rows with similar values from V2 and V3 :
If number and two dicmels are similar then remove all rows but keep one.
For instance 20.322515 and 20.32695  cosider them as similar and remove one

```
 dat=read.table("path/file.txt")
 head(dat)
             V1       V2       V3
          sla1   13.63502   12.98104
          l_2    13.63398   12.98128
          il_3   13.63294   12.98151
          14     23.63190   12.98174
          1_5    23.63086   12.98197
          21_6   23.63489   22.97930
```

desired output:

```
           V1       V2       V3
          il_3   13.63294   12.98151
          14     23.63190   12.98174
          21_6   23.63489   22.97930
```

Comment: Perhaps `df[!duplicated(sapply(df[-1], function(x) sub("(.*\\..{2}).*", "\\1", x))),]`

Comment: In that case, do the duplicated on 'V1' i.e. `df[!duplicated(df$V1),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `floor(x*10^y)` to check if the numbers are equal up to the `y`th digit, so in this case `y=2`, and `10^2=100`.

```
df[!duplicated(floor(df[,c('V2','V3')]*100),fromLast = T),]
```

Output:

```
    V1       V2       V3
3 il_3 13.63294 12.98151
5  1_5 23.63086 12.98197
6 21_6 23.63489 22.97930
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to remove the subtring after the two decimals

```
df[!duplicated(sapply(df[-1], function(x) sub("(.*\\..{2}).*", "\\1", x))),]
```